# Why I can't install Java Extension Pack in Visual Studio

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Why when trying to install java extension pack in VS. I get those errors

```
[2020-12-19 18:36:45.800] [renderer1] [error] ["validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found","    at U.downloadInstallableExtension (file:///C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:635:461)","    at async U.doInstallFromGallery (file:///C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:632:594)"]
[2020-12-19 18:36:45.880] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at U.downloadInstallableExtension (file:///C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:635:461)
    at async U.doInstallFromGallery (file:///C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:632:594)
```

I install it manually with file .vsix and get the following log :

```
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - -------------------------------------------
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - 16.8.3036
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - -------------------------------------------
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - Command line parameters:
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\vscjava.vscode-java-pack-0.12.1.vsix
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - -------------------------------------------
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
19/12/2020 18:38:15 - -------------------------------------------
19/12/2020 18:38:16 - Skipping product Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools (9d27c81e) since it does not support extensions
19/12/2020 18:38:16 - Initializing Install...
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - Détails de l'extension...
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Identifier         : vscode-java-pack
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Name               : Java Extension Pack
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Author             : vscjava
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Version            : 0.12.1
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Description        : Popular extensions for Java development and more.
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Locale             : en-US
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - 
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Produits pris en charge : 
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -           Version : 
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - 
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Références         : 
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - Détails de la signature...
19/12/2020 18:38:17 -   Extension is not signed.
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - 
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - Recherche des produits applicables...
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - Produit installé trouvé - Emplacement global
19/12/2020 18:38:17 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: Une ou plusieurs extensions sont destinées à Visual Studio Code. Essayez de les installer dans Visual Studio Code.
   à VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   à VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   à VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   à VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   à VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   à VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I have tried to install some few other extension of Java like Maven for Java, and I get the error in installing them as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you behind a network proxy?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you may have right. I have changed the whole editor to begin my project asap. I installed NetBeans. Mostly, the error is relating to what you mentionned . I remember I modified some network stuff ago

Answer (score 1):

You can install java on visual-studio-code from this link:
https://aka.ms/vscode-java-installer-win

if you get again any error please drop a comment below to help you

Answer (score 0):

This is the error I get in the installation using your link

```
[20:24:53] Configure Java Settings
[20:24:54] Configure Java Settings ... [Completed]
[20:24:54] Install Java Extensions
[20:25:06] Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'vscjava.vscode-java-pack' v0.12.1...
[20:25:06] Error: (node:264) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
Failed Installing Extensions: vscjava.vscode-java-pack
(node:264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
[20:25:06] Retry ... [1]
[20:25:10] Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'vscjava.vscode-java-pack' v0.12.1...
[20:25:10] Error: (node:12728) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:12728) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
Failed Installing Extensions: vscjava.vscode-java-pack
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:12728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)
[20:25:10] Retry ... [2]
[20:25:13] Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'vscjava.vscode-java-pack' v0.12.1...
[20:25:13] Error occurred
[20:25:13] Error: Error: (node:988) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:988) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
Failed Installing Extensions: vscjava.vscode-java-pack
(node:988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at F.downloadInstallableExtension (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:279:461)
    at async F.doInstallFromGallery (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\cliProcessMain.js:276:594)
(node:988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
[20:25:13] Failed to install Java Extension Pack.
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your operating system??

this file is only for windows

Comment: try to reinstall the vscode and install the package again

Comment: I still have the same error, I also unistall my antivirus, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

In [Java on Visual Studio Code Update – November 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/java-on-visual-studio-code-update-november-2020/), It's strongly recommended that installing the extension pack or [Coding Pack for Java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_coding-pack-for-java) for Java development on VS Code.
Please follow the above link to install **Coding Pack for Java-Windows**.

Answer (score 0):

Currently [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) is available for **Visual Studio Code**, instead of **Visual Studio**.

To enable Java support on Visual Studio Code, you can manually:

1. Install JDK (not JRE) 11+. Because [Language Support for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) requires JDK 11+ to launch itself.
2. [Optional] In VS Code's settings, point `java.home` to the home directory of your JDK. (it's automatically detected if it's pointed by `JAVA_HOME`, included in `PATH`, or installed in default locations.)

Or as mentioned by @user14479250, you can simply run the all-in-one installer, which will install VS Code, JDK 11 and Java extensions if missing.

- Windows: https://aka.ms/vscode-java-installer-win
- Mac: https://aka.ms/vscode-java-installer-mac